# Serializers - Django REST framework (AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

**AttributeError:** Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `UserKeywordSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.

**models.py**

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=500,unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='keywords/', blank=True, null=True)
    mood=models.ManyToManyField(Mood,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class UserKeyword(models.Model):
    keywords=models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
    count=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class KeywordsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Keyword
        fields ='__all__'

class UserKeywordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    keywords = KeywordsSerializer( read_only=True,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserKeyword
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
top_keywords=UserKeyword.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).select_related().order_by('-count')
user_serializer=UserKeywordSerializer(top_keywords).data
print(user_serializer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
top_keywords=UserKeyword.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).select_related().order_by('-count')

user_serializer=UserKeywordSerializer(top_keywords, many=True).data
```

`top_keywords` is queryset,so you should add `many=True` to serializer,see [Dealing with multiple objects](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects).